# Несессионная деавторизация

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// PHP
// коннект к БД mysql
// если пользователь переходит с одной страницы сайта на другую
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    exit();
}
// если пользователь ввел ввел логин и пароль
else {
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
        $pa = md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    }
    $query = "SELECT `password` FROM `table` WHERE login='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
    $lst = @mysql_query($query);
    $passw = mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'password' );
    // ничего - выходим
    if (!$lst) {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();
    }
    // ноль - выходим
    if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0) {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();
    }
    // неверно - выходим
    $a23 =  @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
    if ($pa!= $passw) {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Собственно данный скрипт предназначен для авторизации (да я знаю, что есть авторизация по сессиям, и она лучше). Самый главный плюс данного скрипта - все находится в одном файле, и подключать очень удобно. Единственный минус, который не могу понять как написать - дис авторизация. т.е. кнопку на сайте, при нажатии на которую пользователю бы вновь выпадало окошко, с возможностью ввести логин с пароль. Поможете с решением?

p.s. В теме употребил "не сессессионная" - т.к. не по сессиям. А как эта авторизация называется? Серверная? Авторизация по переменным? Обычная? Дедовская 8-)?

Comment: это пример базовой авторизации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это пример базовой аутентификации. читаем

Чтоб выйти и стать неавторизированным - достаточно уничтожить в массиве  SERVER ключи PHP_AUTH_USER  и PHP_AUTH_PW

а если после аутентификации вывести значение етих переменных - они выводятся? просто есть еще вариант такой 
Начиная с PHP 4.3.0, для того, чтобы предотвратить написание кем-либо скрипта, раскрывающего пароль к странице, которая использует внешнюю аутентификацию, переменные PHP_AUTH не устанавливаются в случае, если данная страница использует внешнюю аутентификацию и установлен безопасный режим. Несмотря на это, переменная REMOTE_USER может использоваться для аутентификации пользователя, прошедшего внешнюю аутентификацию. Таким образом, вы всегда можете воспользоваться переменной $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].

Глянь что есть в переменной $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] еще?

Да как подсказали ниже - попробуй поиграть с куками - щас посмтрел один вариант - мне после нажатия на ссылку выход - в ответ серве присылает измененые куки - и окно опять появляется

ВОт пошарил по инету:

```
Пример #3 Пример HTTP-аутентификации с принудительным вводом новой пары логин/пароль
<?php
function authenticate() {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Test Authentication System"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Вы должны ввести корректный логин и пароль для получения доступа к ресурсу \n";
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ||
    ($_POST['SeenBefore'] == 1 && $_POST['OldAuth'] == $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    authenticate();
} else {
    echo "<p>Добро пожаловать: " . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) . "<br />";
    echo "Предыдущий логин: " . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['OldAuth']);
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='SeenBefore' value='1' />\n";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='OldAuth' value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) . "\" />\n";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Авторизоваться повторно' />\n";
    echo "</form></p>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: пробовал сделать форму, которая делает. потом идет переход на index.php - дис авторизации нет.

    unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

дополню: переменная $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] - пуста (даже если и ее тоже убить, все равно не получается дис авторизоваться)

Answer (score -2):

```
PHP_AUTH_USER и PHP_AUTH_PW
```

Хранятся у клиента в куках на время сессии. и удаляются только при разрыве соединения с сервером.

По-этому тут выход только один закрытие всего браузера целиком. Иначе никак. Так вот сделана Http авторизация.

Переделывай авторизацию на сессии и будет счастье.

Comment: не сказал бы) Работал на чужом приложении с базовой аунтификацией (исходников нет) - так там как раз и была реализация выхода, посленажатии на ссылку- опять вываливалось окно с запросм логина и пароля

Comment: А что, куки удалять религия не позволяет?)

Comment: @Sh4dow А бессмысленно их удалять, эффекта все равно не будет, и я написал именно про 2 куки.Сессия этой базовой закрывается только после закрытия браузера.


@Ale_x ну расскажи как было реализовано, я что-то не верю в это. Скорее всего там была использована сессия, в таком случае ссылочку организовать можно иначе нет.
 у тебя в апдейте реализация ввода новой пары логин пароль, а нужно просто выход ссылочку. Я нехочу вводить заного никакие данные, просто раз нажать и выйти, а тут ввести нужно данные какие-то чтобы разлогиниться - это не решение - это заплатка.

Comment: я больше 2х раз боюсь писать, когда у меня что то не работает - т.к. скажут что руки крюки. в действительности же пытался более часа убивать вообще все переменные, и это не сработало. Код который привел Ale_x, после небольшой правки меня устроил на 99,9999999%

Comment: «Сессия» закрывается не при закрытии браузера, а при получении очередного 401. Т.е. для выхода необходимо и достаточно, чтобы страница логаута одноразово выплюнула 401 (по сути, разово отрицая переданные корректные логин-пароль).

И, да. HTTP'шные credentials ни в каких куках не хранятся. И, тем более, фраза о разрыве соединения с сервером, некорректна (ни `Connection: close` ни `Connection: keep-alive` ни на что, относительно авторизации, не влияют).