# Выход из http авторизации

Tags: html, http, php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Вообщем была такая тема: [про деавторизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126976/php-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Дело в том, что можно авторизоваться повторно, но... немогу переписать данный код, что бы просто выйти, и попасть на определенную страницу. т.е. работает как указанно, но работает "Авторизоваться повторно", что немного не то. Подскажите, как деавторизоваться?

p.s. да да, авторизация по сессиям наше все. сам умею делать такую, и спросил про то, что неумею

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В том то и дело что это косяк и велосипед с граблями.
Что либо ты делаешь так, либо нормальную авторизацию на сессиях и прочих фишках.

Иначе человечество не знает как :)

Comment: ок. нет - тоже ответ